# Is there a base module that implements the slide in, slide out behaviour like the Admin module?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a module that implements slide in and slide out on top functionality, similar to the way some websites slide out a contact form when you click the thingy at the side of the page.
 The [Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) and [Slidebox](http://drupal.org/project/slidebox) modules have that ability, but I am looking for some kind of container object that implements the slide in and out functionality.

PS. the tags are not the most accurate but are the nearest.

Answer (score 1):

Superfish is a great option for drop down menus, and you can customise the effects: http://drupal.org/project/superfish

or Nice Menus: http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus

You can also customise the admin menu to add common tasks, by editing the actual links list.

Comment: I have thought about that, but I need something that slides sideways and can have a block/view/panel embedded in, that is manually opened and closed. drupal.org/project/navigate and drupal.org/project/slideout do something similar, but I am looking for some kind of container object for that kind of functionality.

Comment: Superfish does slide sideways, if you configure it that way - see this demo for the various options: http://mehrpadin.net/demo/superfish/
And these menus are available as blocks so you can embed them anywhere.